# Find a certain number of adjacent entries in an array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, count

I am writing a virtual memory allocation manager in Java. I have a boolean array on *n* entries, and need to find a line of *k* false entries in a row. Apart from doing a massive binary search and counting each lot of falses, is there a decent way of counting for *k* falses, getting the starting index of that line.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `k` will be a significant proportion of `n` then probably the simplest efficiency measure is to skip `k` items in each search.

```
int searchForFalses(boolean[] array, int k) {
    for (int n = 0; n < array.length; n += k) {
        if (!array[n])) {
            int start = n;
            while (start >= 0 && !array[start])
                start--;
            int end = n;
            while (end < array.length && !array[end])
                if (end - start >= k)
                    return start;
                else
                    end++;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, how efficient is is with smaller values of `k`? Trying to find memory for an integer, `k` is 2, with `n` being perhaps 100000. Bigger objects may have a `k` of 1000.

Comment: Clearly it will be inefficient for small values of `k`. If you are regularly going to search for smaller memory segments then you'll need to try a more traditionally mechanism such as holding a free list. Also note that if your algorithm is to just look for the first place which will fit your object then you are going to end up with a lot of fragmentation.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Fragmentation is not too much of a problem in this instance, so I'll look into free lists. Thanks for your input!